# jQuery autoresize pre-filled textarea on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, autoresize

I have a textarea which is created after a successful AJAX call. It may contain quite a lot of text, and I would like it's height to be automatically set so that the whole text would be visible without scrolling.

I am using autoResize plugin (http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/), but it resizes inputs only on user input.

So, how do I resize a textarea so it would fit the text it contains?

Here is the code of the relevant function (var type can be 'input' or 'textarea')

```
function edit_create_input(name, value, type, autocomplete, autoresize)
    {
    var input=$('<' + type + ' class="edit-"' + name + '  name="'+name+'">').val(value); 
    if (autocomplete)
        {
        input.autocomplete("ajax.autosuggest.php",{'multiple':true});
        }
    if (autoresize)
        {
        input.autoResize();
        }
    return input;
```

Comment: Can you show us your current source code? Sometimes lays the solution in front of the eyes. Keep always in mind the saying: "A picture says more than thousand words."

Comment: Perhaps adjusting the plugin code? The code is quite simple and not very long.

Comment: I added the relevant part of my code. Unfortunately, I'm not really good with JS and jQuery, so modifying plugin code is a bit too hard for me at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the <strike>[plugin source](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/plugins/jQuery/autoresize.jquery.js/view)</strike> there are 3 events on which the `updateSize()` function is triggered:

```
// Bind namespaced handlers to appropriate events:
textarea
    .unbind('.dynSiz')
    .bind('keyup.dynSiz', updateSize)
    .bind('keydown.dynSiz', updateSize)
    .bind('change.dynSiz', updateSize);
```

You should Trigger one of these after ajax loads the content:

```
$("#my_textarea").trigger('change.dynSiz');
```

**Edit:** according to your code

```
// ...
if (autoresize)
{
    input.autoResize();
    input.trigger('change.dynSiz');
}
// ...
```

**Note:** using `.trigger()` with the namespaced event is more convenient, since using `.change()` (which is also good) would trigger **every change event** binded to the object, not just the one you need.

**Update:** old plugin source is not available anymore, I could only find a slightly modified version of the original [here](https://gist.github.com/icyleaf/269160).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Could it be because the element is not actually in the DOM at that moment? EDIT: Nope, even if I try this after the element is actually appended, it still doesn't work. I tried testing this in jFiddle, but I couldn't get it to work at all there.

Comment: There is a comment (the last one actually) on the plugin homepage, where someone wants to do just what you want, he just uses `.keydown()` to trigger the event. Could you link your fiddle?

Comment: I did it! Turns out we had different source codes (I had the newer one, from https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery.fn.autoResize). It had different triggers, so `.trigger('change.autoResize')` did it for me! However, I will this seems like a bit of a hack to me, so I'm going to wait a little bit for other answer before accepting this one.

Comment: Actually emulating a user event is more of a trick than a hack, get used to it ;) Glad I could help! Cheers!

Comment: Any idea where this plugin went? James Padolsey's github doesn't seem to have it, and [this link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) returns a 404. The actual source is [still on his site](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/plugins/jQuery/autoresize.jquery.js) but it seems to be the outdated version.

Comment: The plugin is currently located here: http://james.padolsey.com/demos/plugins/jQuery/autoresize.jquery.js/view

Comment: The link is now broken again.

Comment: @dbarros Thanks. I couldn't find the original, but a slightly modified version. See the Update.